# Linkage terminology in drosophila

Tags: genetics

Consider two linked loci that are 50+ map units apart. I perform a test cross between a female that is heterozygous at both loci to a male that is homozygous recessive. In this case, the phenotypic ratio of the offspring will be 1:1:1:1 suggesting that the loci are independently assorting. Then, I cross a heterozygous male to a homozygous recessive female. In this case I will have just two phenotypes due to the lack of recombination in male drosophila. Do I describe the loci as linked or unlinked in this scenario? Do we consider the loci to be linked for males and unlinked for females?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so please tag it as such and read the site guidelines on [homework questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: No it is a hypothetical. I've never actually come across such a scenario nor have I found any information on it. I just want to know about the terminology.